# Передать команду в jsp форме JAVA

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Из заполненой jsp формы, данные передаются на сервер и формируется строка запроса:`site/cmd?name=John&surname=Doe&passport=AB123456&phone=098-765-4321&account=1234567.890`. Но, для того, чтобы эти данные были сохранены в файле и в html была отрисована таблица, нужно, чтобы в строку попала команда (например, "add") и строка должна приобрести вид: `site/cmd?add&name=John&surname=Doe&passport=AB123456&phone=098-765-4321&account=1234567.890`. Как мне поместить эту команду в сроку? Вот сама форма:

```
<div style="width: 300px; margin: 0 auto">
<form id="add_form" method="get" action="cmd">
    <p class="centered" style="width: 300px; margin: 20px">Add Client</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="add"/>//???
    <table style="margin: 20px">
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>
                <label for="name"></label>
                <input style="margin: 5px" type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Surname:</td>
            <td>
                <label for="surname"></label>
                <input style="margin: 5px" type="text" name="surname" id="surname"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Passport:</td>
            <td>
                <label for="passport"></label>
                <input style="margin: 5px" type="text" name="passport" id="passport"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone:</td>
            <td>
                <label for="phone"></label>
                <input style="margin: 5px" type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Account:</td>
            <td>
                <label for="account"></label>
                <input style="margin: 5px" type="text" name="account" id="account"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p><input style="width: 300px" type="submit"/></p>
</form></div>
```

Если я применяю скрытое поле `<input type="hidden" name="add"/>`, команда добавляется, но, естественно, со знаком "=". Как мне правильно добавить команду?

Comment: Сделайте параметр action и его значение add. Получиться, что Вы указываете какое действие хотите сделать. А вообще какое либо добавление делается через POST запрос.

Comment: @ezhov_da А, если не трудно, можно подробнее, какой параметр action и куда его добавить?

Comment: Вы же пишете <input type="hidden" name="add"/>, так используйте <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add"/> и в контроллере берите значение свойства action.